# Need SQL query for output

Tags: mysql

I have table like below

```
empID   |    Ename
------------------
10          (A,B,C)
10           (WM)
```

Need Output as below

```
10(A,B,C,WM)
```

Can any one please help me what is the query to get output ??.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or schema/structure of your tables (the `CREATE TABLE` query). Otherwise, it's quite difficult to give you an accurate answer, because we don't know if the last 2 columns are actually strings or multiple rows within the same table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to follow up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), SO is not a coding service. What attempts have you made?

Answer (score 0):

You need [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbj6enQ8XynHFXHuvycjzx/0

```
SELECT 
   empID,
   GROUP_CONCAT(Ename)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY empID
```